# Create new columns and fill them depending on other in python

Tags: python, pandas

```
ColG Col2 Col3 Len    Sign
G1   1    30   300    +
G2   20   80   200    +
G3   455  720  1000   -
G4   3    40   100    -
G4   2    90   130    +
```

and here is the idea, for each row, if the Sign is `-`, then do :

```
Len-Col2 > NewCol3
Len-Col3 > NewCol2
```

exemple

```
1000-720=280
1000-455=545
100-40=60
100-3=97
```

and get :

```
ColG Col2 Col3 Len    Sign NewCol2  NewCol3
G1   1    30   300    +    1        30
G2   20   80   200    +    20       80
G3   455  720  1000   -    280      545
G4   3    40   100    -    60       97
G4   2    90   130    +    2        90
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: It seems expected output has swapped `col2, col3`

Comment: Oops yes I rectified, it is Len-Col2 that gives NewCol3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need processing each column separately, e.g. compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m = df['Sign'].eq('-')

df['NewCol2'] = np.where(m, df['Len'].sub(df['Col3']), df['Col2'])
df['NewCol3'] = np.where(m, df['Len'].sub(df['Col2']), df['Col3'])
```

Or with [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['NewCol2'] = df['Col2'].mask(m, df['Len'].sub(df['Col3']))
df['NewCol3'] = df['Col3'].mask(m, df['Len'].sub(df['Col2']))

print (df)
  ColG  Col2  Col3   Len Sign  NewCol2  NewCol3
0   G1     1    30   300    +        1       30
1   G2    20    80   200    +       20       80
2   G3   455   720  1000    -      280      545
3   G4     3    40   100    -       60       97
4   G4     2    90   130    +        2       90
```

Answer (score 1):

If your dataframe is not too big, you can try this.

```
def new_col2(row):
  if row['Sign'] == '-':
    return row['Len'] - row['Çol2']
  return row['Col2']

def new_col3(row):
  if row['Sign'] == '-':
    return row['Len'] - row['Çol3']
  return row['Col3']

df['NewCol2'] = df.apply(new_col2, axis=1)
df['NewCol3'] = df.apply(new_col3, axis=1)
```